# SQL Server - Pivot Out Delimited Column Data Into Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two columns of delimited data that I would like to pivot out into individual rows for each data item.  In the starting table below, the delimited data is represented in the **DataPointA** and **DataPointB** columns.  Also, note that each ID is a unique identifier for each person.  The starting table looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
|  ID   | FirstName | LastName | DataPointA | DataPointB |
----------------------------------------------------------
| A1234 | Bill      | Jones    | 1,3,7,8    | 1,4        |
| B5678 | Jane      | Smith    | 2,4,6,9    | 1,5        |
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to take the DataPoint column data that is delimited by commas and create one row for each DataPoint value, while also condensing into one field. So the end result will look like this:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
|  ID   | FirstName | LastName | DataPoint  | DataPointType |
-------------------------------------------------------------
| A1234 | Bill      | Jones    | 1          | A             |
| A1234 | Bill      | Jones    | 3          | A             |
| A1234 | Bill      | Jones    | 7          | A             |
| A1234 | Bill      | Jones    | 8          | A             |
| A1234 | Bill      | Jones    | 1          | B             |
| A1234 | Bill      | Jones    | 4          | B             |
| B5678 | Jane      | Smith    | 2          | A             |
| B5678 | Jane      | Smith    | 4          | A             |
| B5678 | Jane      | Smith    | 6          | A             |
| B5678 | Jane      | Smith    | 9          | A             |
| B5678 | Jane      | Smith    | 1          | B             |
| B5678 | Jane      | Smith    | 5          | B             |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

My first instinct was to use UNPIVOT but I am not able to get it to work on two columns.  Is there another method I should be using?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I hope part of your project is to fix the data. Storing data like this is painful to work with because it violates 1NF.

Comment: I agree, this data is painful to work with.

Comment: *Hopefully* that's the reason they want to "pivot" their data, @SeanLange :)

Comment: That is my hope too @Larnu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need pivoting.  You need string splitting:

```
select t.ID, t.FirstName, t.LastName, v.*
from t cross apply
     (select 'A' as DataPointType, a.value as DataPoint
      from string_split(t.DataPointA, ',') a
      union all
      select 'B' as DataPointType, b.value as DataPoint
      from string_split(t.DataPointB, ',') b
     ) ab;
```

`string_split()` is only available in the most recent versions of SQL Server.  In older versions, you can use your own split function, which can readily be found on the web.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using Microsoft SSMS 2014 which does not have `string_split()` but I will build my own split function and test it out.

Comment: I suggest [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) @FreqTime

Comment: Thank you for your help @Larnu, that function works. I am marking this question as solved.